# Tem como criar um Bookmark sem o atributo id?

Tags: html

Bom, eu tenho essa dúvida porque já li vários artigos de determinados sites e muitos dos autores não colocam o atributo `id` nos elementos o que acaba acontecendo é que se você encontrar seções e querer criar *Bookmarks* na sua página se referencinando para essas seções do site não tem como, muitos dos sites utilizam mais classes.

Como, por exemplo, abaixo ao clicar no link a página atual será direcionada para uma página do **MDN** sobre a *API Geolocation* e a página pulará para uma determinada seção (graças ao atributo `id`):

```html
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API/#Concepts_and_usage" target="_blank">Geolocation API</a>
```

Ok, mas e se não existisse o atributo `id` como em muitos sites e sim um atributo `class`, um elemento sem atributo e etc, teria como pular pelas seções do site para criar o *Bookmark*, sem o atributo `id` ou não?

Comment: Com Js seria possível, mas não tem Pq, a ancora interna eh algo antigo e bem aceito...

Comment: @hugocsl, não é isso amigo! a questão é em sites que não usam o atributo `id` (no caso não o meu e sim de terceiros) como eu faria para o link (do meu site) pular para determinadas seções (do site de terceiros) sem o atributo `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Resposta retirada do stack overflow em inglês, para ver o restante dela basta clicar no link abaixo:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52215052/12096355

### Você não pode

Os elementos em uma página externa não estão acessíveis. As tags `Id 'podem parecer acessíveis, pois você pode ter um URL público que rola para elas, mas essa é uma implementação do navegador. Nenhum outro elemento pode ser acessado assim. Como os elementos que não são de identificação não estão acessíveis, você não pode dizer ao navegador que deseja rolar para eles. Você não pode nem dizer ao navegador que deseja rolar uma distância fixa em uma página externa; simplesmente não há como fazê-lo em HTML ou JavaScript.